# Laravel 5.5 - save(); wont save to the database and does not output an error

Tags: laravel

I am trying to make an registration form with laravel 5.5 and mysql but the problem is it wont submit to the database..

PageController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class PageController extends Controller
{
public function main(){
if (!Auth::Check()) {
return view('auth.login');
}
return view('user.main');
 }

public function register_check(Request $request){
$this->validate($request, [

'username' => 'required|min:2|max:12|unique:users',
    'fname' => 'required|min:5|max:20',
    'position' => 'required|not_in:0',
    'password' => 'required|min:6|max:12',
    'ConfirmPass' => 'required|same:password',
    'contactnum' => 'required|min:2|max:12'

]);

$user = new User;
        $user->username = $request['username'];
        $user->fname = $request['fname'];
        $user->position= $request['position'];
        $user->password = bcrypt($request['password']);
        $user->ConfirmPass = $request['ConfirmPass'];
        $user->contactnum = $request['contactnum'];
        $user->save();

    }
        }
```

route web.php

```
Route::get('/', [
'as'=>'index',
'uses'=> 'PageController@main'
]);

Route::get('/register', [
'as'=>'register',
'uses'=> 'PageController@register'
]);

Route::post('/register_check', [
'as'=>'register_check',
'uses'=>'PageController@register_check'
]);
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. thank you in advance

Comment: Please show the form and describe what exactly happens when you press submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing **there is an error in validation and you are being redirected back to the form**. You might not be checking for `$errors` in your form view hence you don't see what the error is.

Place this code in your form view file. To see if there are any validation errors.

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: thank you sir Sapnesh Naik and Mayank Pandeyz ... i found out that I didn't put a name in the select tag...  instead in the select tag I put it in the label... sorry for disturbance...

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with such situation is to check the response of `save()` function like:

```
if( $user->save() )
{
    // Success message here
}
else
{
    // Failure message here
}
```

now you will gt to know whether the save is successful or not.